# How to change classes with using JavaScript which has no ID?

Tags: javascript

I am in trouble with changing the value of this code. In this code, I wanna change the class "selected" with a number set by JavaScript code.

Briefly speaking, I wanna reach the "li" items and give let say: 4 as a value, and it will add "selected" to the related class and will delete the previous one.

Edit: Additionally, it should also change the < div class="select-box">1< /div> value accordingly.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="select-container xl" id="_channel">
  <label class="select-title T_channel xl">Channel:</label>&nbsp;
  <div class="tp-select">
  <div class="select-box">1</div>
  <div class="select-icon-container"><span class="select-icon"></span></div>
    <ul class="drop-down" style="max-height: 204.55px; display: none;">
      <li style="cursor: default; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);"></li>
      <li data-val="0" class="option-item">Auto</li>
      <li data-val="1" class="option-item selected">1</li>
      <li data-val="2" class="option-item">2</li>
      <li data-val="3" class="option-item">3</li>
      <li data-val="4" class="option-item">4</li>
      <li data-val="5" class="option-item">5</li>
      <li data-val="6" class="option-item">6</li>
      <li data-val="7" class="option-item">7</li>
      <li data-val="8" class="option-item">8</li>
      <li data-val="9" class="option-item">9</li>
      <li data-val="10" class="option-item">10</li>
      <li data-val="11" class="option-item">11</li>
      <li data-val="12" class="option-item">12</li>
      <li data-val="13" class="option-item">13</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks;

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("selected")`? `document.querySelector(".selected")`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This line of code only selects the code. Not removing the previous one or not adding a new one accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let x = document.querySelector(".select-box").innerText;

let options = document.querySelectorAll("li.option-item");
options.forEach(item => {
  if (item.getAttribute("data-val") == x){
      item.classList.add("selected");
  }
  else{
      item.classList.remove("selected");
  }
});

console.log(options);
```

```html
<div class="select-container xl" id="_channel">
  <label class="select-title T_channel xl">Channel:</label>&nbsp;
  <div class="tp-select">
  <div class="select-box">4</div>
  <div class="select-icon-container"><span class="select-icon"></span></div>
    <ul class="drop-down" style="max-height: 204.55px; display: none;">
      <li style="cursor: default; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);"></li>
      <li data-val="0" class="option-item">Auto</li>
      <li data-val="1" class="option-item selected">1</li>
      <li data-val="2" class="option-item">2</li>
      <li data-val="3" class="option-item">3</li>
      <li data-val="4" class="option-item">4</li>
      <li data-val="5" class="option-item">5</li>
      <li data-val="6" class="option-item">6</li>
      <li data-val="7" class="option-item">7</li>
      <li data-val="8" class="option-item">8</li>
      <li data-val="9" class="option-item">9</li>
      <li data-val="10" class="option-item">10</li>
      <li data-val="11" class="option-item">11</li>
      <li data-val="12" class="option-item">12</li>
      <li data-val="13" class="option-item">13</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this actually worked pretty fine for the purpose. And it is my mistake to mention about one more issue -I will edit the question-
It should also change the <div class="select-box">1</div> with the value of x

Comment: I am waiting for your comeback, is your problem  solved ?

Comment: Hi @Osman Durdag. Thank you so much for your answers. It solved my problem, but I needed to add some more lines according to my project structure.

Answer (score 1):

Use a query selector that matches the class and `data-val` value.

```js
// Remove the old selected item
document.querySelectorAll(".option-item.selected").forEach(item => item.classList.remove("selected"));

// Select the desired item
document.querySelector(".option-item[data-val='4']").classList.add("selected");
```

```css
.option-item.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-container xl" id="_channel">
  <label class="select-title T_channel xl">Channel:</label>&nbsp;
  <div class="tp-select"><div class="select-box">1</div>
  <div class="select-icon-container"><span class="select-icon"></span></div>
    <ul class="drop-down" style="max-height: 204.55px;">
      <li style="cursor: default; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);"></li>
      <li data-val="0" class="option-item">Auto</li>
      <li data-val="1" class="option-item selected">1</li>
      <li data-val="2" class="option-item">2</li>
      <li data-val="3" class="option-item">3</li>
      <li data-val="4" class="option-item">4</li>
      <li data-val="5" class="option-item">5</li>
      <li data-val="6" class="option-item">6</li>
      <li data-val="7" class="option-item">7</li>
      <li data-val="8" class="option-item">8</li>
      <li data-val="9" class="option-item">9</li>
      <li data-val="10" class="option-item">10</li>
      <li data-val="11" class="option-item">11</li>
      <li data-val="12" class="option-item">12</li>
      <li data-val="13" class="option-item">13</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this actually worked pretty fine for the purpose. And it is my mistake to mention about one more issue -I will edit the question- It should also change the <div class="select-box">1</div> with the value accordingly

Answer (score 0):

you should use getElementsByClassName

So your code will look something like

```
document.getElementsByClassName("selected")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This line of code only selects the code. Not removing the previous one or not adding a new one accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want all the li elements with "selected" and then modify the class of a specific element. A js code like this should work.

```
//remove the selected class first 
document.querySelector("selected").className = "option-item"

//get all li items with class option-item
listOfLi = document.querySelectorAll("li.option-item")


selectedElement = listOfLi.filter(e=>e.data-val==4)//whatever value you want to match it with

selectedElement.className = whatever classes you want to assign.(eg."selected")
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for `nth-child`

For example

```js
var selectedElement = document.querySelector(".drop-down:nth-child(4)");
selectedElement.classList.add('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to the `ul` and then select the nth child element.

```
const selected = 4
documentGetElementById(‘myUl’)
  .childNodes[selected-1]
  .classList
  .add(‘selected’)
```